# OR condition check in dynamic SOQL query for multiple picklist value

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

Getting error while executing SOQL query. We have `Address_Type__C` is a picklist field having multiple value. We are checking for the multiple value's in the OR condition. Is the Query seems correct?? Need some inputs.

```
private string sampleSoqlQuery = 'select id,Contact__r.id,Contact__r.firstname,Contact__r.lastname,Country__c,Postcode__c,State__c,Street_Name__c,Street_Number__c,Street_Type__c,Unit_No__c,Address_Type__c,Suburb__c from Address__c Where (Address_Type__c= \'Residential\' OR \'Investment Property\' OR \'Principal Business\' OR \'Registered Business\') AND Contact__r.id IN :conIds'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the field in question is a multiselect picklist then you will have to use `INCLUDES` to compare field values.

So in your case, your query will be

`Address_Type__c INCLUDES ('Residential','Investment Property','Principal Business','Registered Business')`

So your overall dynamic query will be

```
private string sampleSoqlQuery = 'select id,Contact__r.id,Contact__r.firstname,Contact__r.lastname,Country__c,Postcode__c,State__c,Street_Name__c,Street_Number__c,Street_Type__c,Unit_No__c,Address_Type__c,Suburb__c from Address__c Where Address_Type__c INCLUDES (\'Residential\' , \'Investment Property\' , \'Principal Business\' , \'Registered Business\') AND Contact__r.id IN :conIds'
```

You can go through [Querying Multi-Select Picklists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm) for more help on this topic.

--------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------

The issue with your SOQL query is that you are not following `fieldExpression1 OR fieldExpression2` pattern i.e.

`Address_Type__c= 'Residential' OR 'Investment Property' OR 'Principal Business' OR 'Registered Business'`

will not work, it will have to be replaced with either with `IN` operator

`Address_Type__c IN ('Residential','Investment Property','Principal Business','Registered Business')`

OR you can compare the values individually

`Address_Type__c= 'Residential' OR Address_Type__c= 'Investment Property'  OR Address_Type__c= 'Principal Business' OR Address_Type__c= 'Registered Business'`

You can go through [Write SOQL Queries](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql) module in trailhead to learn more on this.

Comment: @Venkat : Updated the answer for multiselect picklist fields, check if that works for you.

Comment: The Picklist is not a multiselect. I just want to order the valueof the query as per the picklist value check.

Comment: What do you mean by this "I just want to order the valueof the query as per the picklist value check"

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` operator.

```
private string sampleSoqlQuery = 'select id,Contact__r.id,Contact__r.firstname,Contact__r.lastname,Country__c,Postcode__c,State__c,Street_Name__c,Street_Number__c,Street_Type__c,Unit_No__c,Address_Type__c,Suburb__c from Address__c Where Address_Type__c IN (\'Residential\' , \'Investment Property\' , \'Principal Business\' , \'Registered Business\') AND Contact__r.id IN :conIds'
```

Comment: private string sampleSoqlQuery = 'select id,Contact__r.id,Contact__r.firstname,Contact__r.lastname,Country__c,Postcode__c,State__c,Street_Name__c,Street_Number__c,Street_Type__c,Unit_No__c,Address_Type__c,Suburb__c from Address__c Where Address_Type__c IN (\'Residential\' , \'Investment Property\' , \'Principal Business\' , \'Registered Business\') AND Contact__r.id IN :conIds' using IN does not satisfy OR condition which i want to check Either values.

Comment: @Venkat have you tried it?

Comment: I have verified it is pulling all the related thing, should be sorted as per the picklist value written in the query.

Comment: @Venkat Then use order by to sort it, refer [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm](this link).

Comment: I Didn't found how to use order by to sort by the picklist value as follows: 1.Resendential, 2. Investment Property 3.Principal Business 4.Registered Business.

Comment: Order by sorts alphabetically, this is not possible. you need to sort it in apex.

Comment: can you suggest some code to achieve that? It will be helpful to me.

Comment: I would suggest adding numbers in the picklist values so it will be sorted automatically.like `1. Residential, 2. Investment Property 3.Principal Business 4.Registered Business`.

Comment: The picklist values are Predefined we can't change them. We sort them from the back end through apex as per the requirement. Can you suggest anything which will fulfill the criteria.